# Why is bootstrap cutting off some of my text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I originally created my resume without Bootstrap in xhtml and css. Now I am wanting to incorporate Bootstrap to learn more about it. However, once I added Bootstrap I'm having a problem with aligning text in one spot. I've attached an image showing the issue.

[image]
[image]

As you can see, I have a container with a row and a few stipulations about the size of the elements in the row. I have my number, github, and email on the left, and my address on the right. The address on the right should be adhering to the contact-right class, which has `float: right; text-align: right;` set, but it's not and it has a left align. Here's the relevant CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
body {
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 30%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-width: 400px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.education-right {
    float: right;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    text-align: right;
}
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 768px) {
body {
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.0em;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.education-right {
    float: right;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    text-align: right;
}

.contact-right {
    float: right;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    text-align: right;
}
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
body {
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-width: 300px;
    line-height: 1.0em;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 4px;
}

.education-right, .contact-right {
    margin-left: 29px
}
}
```

Comment: `float:right` will push the div to the right side of the page. Seeing as though you're using bootstrap's atomic classes to set the width of that container to 6 columns, then it looks like it's displaying as you've written.
Add `text-align: right` to your `.contact-right` class, and I'm sure it'll work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were facing problem because of `margin-left` and `margin-right` assigned to your `<body>`

Remove those properties and it will work fine.

> Assign `pull-right` class to `contact-right` instead of using `float:right`

```css
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-width: 400px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .contact-right {
    line-height: 0.8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.0em;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .education-right {
    line-height: 0.8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .contact-right {
    line-height: 0.8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-width: 300px;
    line-height: 1.0em;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 4px;
  }
  .education-right,
  .contact-right {
    margin-left: 29px
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="contact-left col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <p>123456789</p>
      <p><a>github@github.com</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-right col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <p style="color:red; font-weight:900;">Problem Element Below</p>
      <a>Address won't cut this time, 12345 </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dhaval, I think you meant my `margin-left` in `.contact-right` instead of my `body`, but yes you were right!